# GoDaddy hosting not working with email

Tags: php, email, godaddy, gmail

I have a simple template for my website and two versions. One is `.co` (GoDaddy) and the other is `.co.nz`(Another Company). I'm using a basic PHP form that sends email successful to Google Gmail, however when I try changing the destination email address to non-gmail, it fails, strangely the other hosting account accepts both destinations.

Here is my PHP form:

```
$mail = @mail(WEBMASTER_EMAIL, "Contact Form -BUSINESS-.", $message,
     "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
    ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
    ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
```

Comment: What are you specifying as the "From:" email address?

Comment: Any errors thrown?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I called Godaddy support and it sucks, so you need to access MX Entry in cPanel and configure it to remote MX if your email server is outside godaddy. Remember that you have to send emails from PHP trought your own domain. You need to specify a mx record in order to send the emails, it works for me with a delay of 10 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

If you use, Godaddy email or hosting provider email, you can configure your SMTP details in your PHP to avoid non delivery.

Comment: What does the SMTP need to be configured as?

Comment: i dont know much about php, but if you are using any php frameworks, there should be an option to config smtp.. but to get you an idea, im using phpmailer to send email for my own domain like "me@emjimadhu.com".. for this i needed to config smtp details in my phpmailer function.. i think these two links can help you, if you are using phpmailer.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618712/sending-emails-through-smtp-with-phpmailer) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256582/phpmailer-smtp-configuration) hope it helps..